# what happens to subscribe event of web3 if something goes wrong?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, dapps

If network gone, RPC is down, or something like that happen. then what would happen with the subscribe events of web3 js or python. do we need some additional codes to handle crash or subscribe event will do it automatically.
code reference: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-subscribe.html#id7

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to take care of any error handling if the event emitter returned from the subscription emits the "error" event.

From the documentation:

> EventEmitter: An subscription instance as an event emitter with the
> following events:
>
> "data" returns String: Fires on each incoming pending transaction and
> returns the transaction hash. 
> "error" returns Object: Fires when an
> error in the subscription occurs.

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
})
.on("data", function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction);
})
.on("error", () => {
    //handle error
});
```